# AWS Opensearch Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, opensearch

while creating index or searching document in AWS opensearch serverless collection from node.js project, it throws error as "User don't have permission for requested resource"[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAlQj.png)

[This is my iam permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AETrk.png)

I attempt to index the document using the sample code in AWS OpenSearch Serverless Documentation. I was hoping to look for a indexing that certain document in a opensearch Serverless collection.

Comment: What is the IAM permission used by the NodeJS application can you share the details.

Comment: i have included my IAM permission used  by node js application. That includes amazon Opensearch service full access.